# Elasticsearch Date Range Aggregation with Sum

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch

I've followed [Elastic's docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html) and successfully queried my index to return data for two date ranges.

What I can't get right, is adding a sum of units to each range. I've managed to add a unit sum (see query below) but this only returns a sum for the entire range.

What I'm trying to achieve is a period A vs B comparison. i.e. This week you've sold X units vs Y units last week and therefore the % variance is Z.

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "filtered":{  
         "query":{  
            "query_string":{  
               "query":"*",
               "analyze_wildcard":true
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "vendor_type":{  
         "terms":{  
            "field":"vendor_type",
            "size":5
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "product_type":{  
               "terms":{  
                  "field":"product_type",
                  "size":5,
                  "order":{  
                     "unit_sum":"desc"
                  }
               },
               "aggs":{  
                  "range":{  
                     "date_range":{  
                        "field":"date",
                        "format":"MM-yyy",
                        "ranges":[  
                           {  
                              "to":"now-1M/M"
                           },
                           {  
                              "from":"now-1M/M"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  "unit_sum":{  
                     "sum":{  
                        "field":"units"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to move (or copy) your `unit_sum` inside the `range` aggregation, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "*",
          "analyze_wildcard": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "vendor_type": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "vendor_type",
        "size": 5
      },
      "aggs": {
        "product_type": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "product_type",
            "size": 5
          },
          "aggs": {
            "range": {
              "date_range": {
                "field": "date",
                "format": "MM-yyy",
                "ranges": [
                  {
                    "to": "now-1M/M"
                  },
                  {
                    "from": "now-1M/M"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "aggs": {
                "unit_sum": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "units"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ha, I'm certain I tried that already and it failed saying unknown aggregation 'unit_sum'. Tried the above and it just did again, but I then released the ordering under product type needed to come out and it worked! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh, I missed the ordering, sorry. Good call!

Comment: Now this is working, i've realised it's not exactly what I need. The to/from gives me all values before and after the set date/time but instead I need results for two specific date ranges. I've tried changing the to/from to a pair of gte/lte clauses but that's not working. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to to add to and from in the same hash `{"to":"...", "from":""}` instead of in separate ones.